# Изучение Objective-C для знающих Java

Tags: java, android, ios, swift

После освоения Java и написания приложения для Android, возникла необходимость в плотном изучении Objective-C, с целью реализовать проект и на iOS.

Может кто подскажет, существуют ли в природе открытые курсы/документация для людей, узнавших многое из Java и желающих освоить Objective-C, как бы проводящих аналогии этих двух языков. Ведь они оба ООП и, как мне кажется, различаются лишь синтаксисом. Или не стоит замарачиваться, а просто с чистого листа начать изучение для iOS?

Так же интересует вопрос о Swift. Существенно ли он *лучше* Objective-C, даёт ли большие возможности программисту по сравнению с ним или же просто его аналог с упрошенными синтаксисом?

Если кто поделится интересными и полезными ресурсами по обучению Objective-C либо Swift, то буду очень благодарен.
Когда-то очень по Андроиду помогли известные StartAndroid и лекции Александра Климова (можно сказать, с нуля по ним и научился всему сам).
Может есть что-то аналогичное под iOS...

Comment: Смотря что вы вкладываете в понятие «лучше». _Выразительнее_ — да. _Мощнее_ — нет.

Comment: Про отличия swift'а от Objective C вы можете почитать, как ни странно, [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/swift/info).

Comment: Смотри. Objective-C: синтаксис, напоминающий монстра франкенштейна, сшитого из одного живого (C) и одного мертвого (Smalltalk) языка; упоротая к чертям объектно-ориентированная модель Smalltalk, отличающаяся меньшей оптимальностью, чем тот же C++ (мягко говоря, каждый вызов метода превращается в два). В Swift такой фигни нету, зато есть 100500 крутых удобств, в том числе функциональных. Собсно выбирай =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если цель - создать приложение под iOS - изучайте Swift! Его легче освоить и не будет ощущения погружения в доисторические языки, заодно кучу модерновых фишек узнаете и по синтаксису он больше похож на нормальный язык программирования, в отличие от Objective-C. Полезный ресурс: http://www.raywenderlich.com - лучшие, на мой взгляд, обучалки по iOS. Ну и официальная книга от Apple по языку Swift, примеры из которой можно открыть прямо в xCode

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, как бы не был круче или не круче swift, учить обжектив придется хотя бы потому, что любая более-менее приличная софтверная компания уже имеет кучу кода на обжективе. Держать же десяток программистов, которые могут одно и не могут другого в здравом уме не будет никто - слишком дорого обходится. Посему, как бизнес, так и вменяемые программисты скорее предпочтут обжектив, по крайней мере, пока есть куча кода, который переписывать никто не будет. Что же касается курсов - очень круты big nerd ranch. Они очень и очень недешевы, однако, есть вполне вменяемые учебники на их основе.